# with tabset row i want display buttons in angualr2

Tags: html, css, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

in a single row, i want display tabset+buttons. tabset  already displayed, now I want to display buttons

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-8 ">
        <div class="col-lg-8" style="margin-top:35px;" >

 <h6 class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >Select File</button></h6>
 <h5 class="text-right"> <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/summary']" >Go</button></h5>

            <tabset>

                <tab>
                    <ng-template tabHeading><strong>Content</strong></ng-template>

                </tab>
                <tab>
                    <ng-template tabHeading><strong>Meta Data</strong></ng-template>

                </tab>



            </tabset>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have tried yet? Show us your code.

Comment: <ul class="col-lg-8 text-right" >
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      
    </ul>

Comment: it display another line

Comment: Add your HTML code and corresponding CSS in snippet

Comment: see the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this (used bootstrap):

```css
button.btn-secondary {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:35px;">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<tabset>
<tab>
<ng-template tabHeading><strong>Content</strong></ng-template>
</tab>
<tab>
<ng-template tabHeading><strong>Meta Data</strong></ng-template>
</tab>
</tabset>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm pull-right"  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/summary']" >Go</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm pull-right" >Select File</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hemalatha, do you mean like this?